# .NET SupportedOSPlatformAttribute: what values my I validly use?

Tags: .net, attributes

I've got this attribute in an AssemblyInfo file.  Right now it's set to this:

```
System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows7.0")]
```

As per the docs, the idea at the time was to keep anyone from trying to use the software on anything earlier than windows 7

But I have no memory of where I got the actual literal string "windows7.0".    Is there some documented list of valid platforms to use?  Do I just say, "windows8.0" for windows 8?  "windows10.0" for windows 10? etc?  The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.supportedosplatformattribute?view=net-6.0) does not seem to give any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it's not just a platform but platform version which seems to be build as simple string concatenation. There are multiple examples in the [platform compatibility analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/platform-compat-analyzer) article in the docs.

Also AFAIK you should be able to use RIDs (Runtime Identifiers) for this, see more [at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) and in the [github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json).

Also OS-specific TFMs (target framework moniker) [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms) can be useful.